# Entering bios from grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bios, grubrescue

I was running two os - Windows and Linux, but I've deleted my previous linux  distribution because I wanted to install ubuntu instead and I accidentally forgot to fix MBR and right now I'm stuck with grub rescue. And I wanted to ask, if there is any way to enter bios to set boot order to as a first priority so I can fix this? Pressing function keys, esc and delete didn't work, so I hope that maybe there is another way. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Typing `fwsetup` into the grub prompt should take you from the grub rescue into the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not from the GRUB rescue shell. You need to enter the BIOS *before* GRUB shows up. The details depend on your machine but there should be a message displayed during [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) that tells you what key to press to enter "Setup".

The key is often one of <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>, so try those if you don't see a message. You need to do this *before* the GRUB screen loads though.

Comment: F2 is another common one. Some computers even use Esc. There is frustratingly *no* standardization on this critical issue.

Comment: @RodSmith There wasn't a standard before, with BIOS, so I'm not exoecting one now for UEFI.